# GitKraken adds \ufeff to the start of file

Tags: git, byte-order-mark, gitkraken

When I push commits to Bitbucket and create pull-request, I can see in a diff a [weird symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiukC.jpg) (\ufeff) is added to the start of newly created files.

I don't want GitKraken to add any additional symbols, so the commits would have been pure. How to achieve that?

Comment: What editor are you using to edit the files? That's likely the cause of your issue.

Comment: @bk2204, I use Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.
Before GitKraken I used SourceTree and after I switched from SourceTree to GitKraken the issue has appeared. So I don't think the problem is caused by editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, when Visual Studio writes a file, either in UTF-16 or UTF-8, it writes a byte order mark (BOM, U+FEFF) to the beginning of the file. This mark is required when using UTF-16, but it's widely considered a bad idea to write it in files with UTF-8.

Normally, a byte order mark is zero-width, so the likely reason you're seeing it in GitKraken and not SourceTree is because GitKraken explicitly shows it, whereas SourceTree probably does not.

If you're saving files as UTF-8 in Visual Studio, you need to save them manually as "UTF-8 without signature". If you save them using the default mode, it saves them with a BOM.

Alternatively, you can add an [`.editorconfig` file](https://editorconfig.org/) to your project which sets the default character set as `utf-8`. That will direct Visual Studio not to write a BOM in your files. If your project is reticent to adopt such a file, you can create one yourself and ignore it by adding `.editorconfig` to its own line in `.git/info/exclude`.

Answer (score 0):

On a recent git adding the following to `.gitattributes` should solve your problem :

```
 *.cpp text working-tree-encoding=UTF-8 eol=CRLF
```

Replace `cpp` by whatever file type you need

*Note:* See the .gitattributes [man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)

- for your as well as all your coworkers' gits (they should all support)
- also check the `iconv` call working given there